# Kendo row editing

Tags: kendo-ui

```
e.container.find("input[name=test]").change(function() {    

    var grid = $("#test").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    **grid.editRow(grid.tbody.children().last());**        
    return false;       

})
```

Now the code making last row is editable but I want to make changed row is editable.

Comment: What kind of change are you referring to here? Can you post a dojo/JsFiddle which could explain your question better?

Comment: Try `grid.editRow($(this).closest("tr"))`